# How to get Selenium work with Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, selenium

I'm trying to scrape some data and display it on my spring boot app however the workings of Selenium seems to be different than the usual Java program. I'm getting all sorts of errors while trying to implement Selenium. Also, should I put chromedriver.exe under resources?

Web scraping class

```
@Service
public class WebScrape {

    final static private String url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/";
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    public List<Data>getAllData(){
                
        return allData;
    }
    
}
```

pom.xml

```html
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Edit: Even with Selenium in Pom and default spring boot dependency, the import statements do not work

[image]

Comment: All sorts of errors? What does it mean?

Comment: The import doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your Selenium code as part of application logic itself you should not provide `test` scope to your dependencies. Use `compile`.

When you use `test` scope, your libraries are only included when you run test phase.

Comment: I'm still getting errors after adding that, edited the question

Comment: Do you still have issues with imports? I cannot say anything looking at your screen shot.

Comment: Imports are fine, it is the code that uses the imports. Also I'm going to load chromedriver.exe from resource file

Comment: You have corrupted structure of your code in your screen shot. You cannot call browser.manage where you define class fields.

Comment: Basically you cannot run instructions in fields section and you cannot define methods within other methodd

Comment: That worked. Should I put the entire loading process in a method? If so, I'm not sure if the webdriver is accessible in another method. I could copy paste the load browser code in all the web scrapping methods but that would seem repetitive

Comment: I am not sure what would be the best way. Depends on what do you expect from your app. If it is a web app it is multithreaded so there could be huge number of problems to resolve. You have to think of all possible use cases carefully.

Comment: I shared all details here: https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-spring-boot-cucumber-junit5-project/